# Bibliography with enumerate

Tags: bibliographies, enumerate

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, A4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}

\begin{document}

\section{References}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Autor, David, David Dorn, Gordon Hanson, and Kaveh Majlesi (2016). ``A Note on the Effect of Rising Trade Exposure on the 2016 Presidential Election.'' Mimeo, MIT Department of Economics.

\item Baldwin, Richard (2016). \emph{The Great Convergence. Information Technology and the New Globalization}. Cambridge: Harvard University Press.

\item Baumeister, Roy F. and Mark R. Leary (1995). ``The Need to Belong: Desire for Interpersonal Attachments as a Fundamental Human Motivation''. \emph{Psychological Bulletin}, 117:497-529.

\item Bavetta, Sebastiano and Francesco Guala, (2003). ``Autonomy Freedom and Deliberation''. \emph{Journal of Theoretical Politics}, 15: 423-443.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The above is a bibliography for a paper. When I use enumerate each reference is marked as 1. and so on. I would like to have [1] instead. I know that I can reach that result by using an appropriate style and bibtex. However, I need to use enumerate. Any hint about? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use  the `thebibliography` environment, if you want a hand-made bibliography?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *need to use `enumerate`*, you can use a package like [`enumerate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) or [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to manipulate `enumerate`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[12pt, A4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{References}

\begin{enumerate}[{label=[\arabic{*}]}]

\item Autor, David, David Dorn, Gordon Hanson, and Kaveh Majlesi (2016). ``A Note on the Effect of Rising Trade Exposure on the 2016 Presidential Election.'' Mimeo, MIT Department of Economics.

\item Baldwin, Richard (2016). \emph{The Great Convergence. Information Technology and the New Globalization}. Cambridge: Harvard University Press.

\item Baumeister, Roy F. and Mark R. Leary (1995). ``The Need to Belong: Desire for Interpersonal Attachments as a Fundamental Human Motivation''. \emph{Psychological Bulletin}, 117:497-529.

\item Bavetta, Sebastiano and Francesco Guala, (2003). ``Autonomy Freedom and Deliberation''. \emph{Journal of Theoretical Politics}, 15: 423-443.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: enumerate solution]

If you only want a handmade bibliography you can use `thebibliography`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, A4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}% 9 is a pattern for the item labels
\bibitem{Autor2016} Autor, David, David Dorn, Gordon Hanson, and Kaveh Majlesi (2016). ``A Note on the Effect of Rising Trade Exposure on the 2016 Presidential Election.'' Mimeo, MIT Department of Economics.

\bibitem{Baldwin2016} Baldwin, Richard (2016). \emph{The Great Convergence. Information Technology and the New Globalization}. Cambridge: Harvard University Press.

\bibitem{Baumeister1995} Baumeister, Roy F. and Mark R. Leary (1995). ``The Need to Belong: Desire for Interpersonal Attachments as a Fundamental Human Motivation''. \emph{Psychological Bulletin}, 117:497-529.

\bibitem{Bavetta2003} Bavetta, Sebastiano and Francesco Guala, (2003). ``Autonomy Freedom and Deliberation''. \emph{Journal of Theoretical Politics}, 15: 423-443.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: thebibliography solution]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, for a manual bibliography, is to use the `\thebibliography` environment, which is a dedicated list environment.  If you just want the list of references, you can do it this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt, A4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
%
\item Autor, David, David Dorn, Gordon Hanson, and Kaveh Majlesi (2016). ``A Note on the Effect of Rising Trade Exposure on the 2016 Presidential Election.'' Mimeo, MIT Department of Economics.
%
\item Baldwin, Richard (2016). \emph{The Great Convergence. Information Technology and the New Globalization}. Cambridge: Harvard University Press.
%
\item Baumeister, Roy F. and Mark R. Leary (1995). ``The Need to Belong: Desire for Interpersonal Attachments as a Fundamental Human Motivation''. \emph{Psychological Bulletin}, 117:497-529.
%
\item Bavetta, Sebastiano and Francesco Guala, (2003). ``Autonomy Freedom and Deliberation''. \emph{Journal of Theoretical Politics}, 15: 423-443.
%
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The argument `{9}` of the environment is used to set the maximum width of the labels.  If the labels will have up to 2 digits, you' use `{99}`, and so on.

If the items have to be referable in the text (`\cite` command), you have to use `\bibitem{citation key}` in the place of `\item`.